# #define mockable virtual in C++

Tags: c++

I found this code:

`#define mockable virtual`

Do you have any idea why somebody will define virtual like this? I'm just curios what's the point of doing this

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So that you could do:

```
class ClassIdLikeToTest{
    mockable void mymethod(){
         //Behavior I would like to be different in my tests
    }
}
```

And then define mockable as virtual for the test build so that you can override that method inheriting from the class.

You write your test and use a class that inherits from ClassIdLikeToTest and overrides mymethod, and it will work as long as mockable is virtual, but then you can remove it for production builds and those functions will not be virtual, and you don't pay for the virtual call.

Comment: The chosen name, *mockable*, is also descriptive. functions declared "mockable" can be "mocked".. that is, a *mock function* can be used in its place for testing purposes